# width: 100% issue

Tags: css

this kind of stuff has always eluded me.  i have a div that is as wide as the window (width: 100%)  that has a vertical javascript customized scrollbar within an iframe, also as wide and the scrollbar is 10px wide.  i just want the div to be 10px less than 100% so the scrollbar will show.  how does this happen?  please let me know.  thanks!

Comment: as if helping someone is lesser than 15 imaginary reputation points :))

Comment: `width: 100%` makes the element as wide as its parent, not the window.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a negative right margin of -10px

Comment: its not safe to give negative margin as it doesn't work properly...on IE.